# how do i delete something after spawn

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the game starts, the bomb drops from above with the spawn system. How to delete dropped bombs after 7 seconds

[image: unity]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but easiest [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) has an optional parameter

> The optional amount of time to delay before destroying the object.

so just do e.g.

```
Destroy(enemyGameObject, 7f);
```

to destroy the GameOebjct after 7 seconds.

Comment: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object data, UnityEngine.Vector3 pos, UnityEngine.Quaternion rot) (at <ad3eaa0878d94cbe8e45f9c494d71647>:0)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, SpawnerD.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnerD.cs:23)

Comment: In your code from the screenshot there is nothing on line 23 ... what exactly does the exception point to?

Comment: @NOVAPATTİS After some research, you may be referencing a destroyed gameobject, meaning you could have the wrong variable input. What is the section of code this error occurs at?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Timer (in "using System.Timers") in the bomb's script.

When the bomb spawns, the object's script Awake() method executes, and there you can setup and start your timer.

The problem is that you will need to create a new bomb object each time you spawn one, so i'm assuming your spawn system does that.

```
using System.Timers

Timer _timer;
private void Awake()
{
   _timer = new Timer();
   _timer.Interval = 7000; // in miliseconds
   _timer.Elapsed += DestroyThisObject;
   _timer.Start();
}

private void HandleThisObject(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
   // Here you handle your object. Be careful if the spawn system 
   // tries to access this object again if the instance is 
   // disposed as it could break the game.
   // I suggest reusing the item.
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example command?

Comment: This is possible but not really a good idea in Unity, you are not allowed to implement constructors for `MonoBhaviour`

Comment: @derHugo If i remember correctly the name is Awake(). It can be used to make this. Going to fix the name.
NOVAPATTİS I will post some code!

Comment: `DestroyThisObject` here might get called on a different thread .. this is not allowed for Unity API like Destroy

Comment: @derHugo As far as i know, there shouldn't be a problem if the call doesn't need to be called from a specific thread. Does this behave differently in this case?

I left the method empty because there could be a lot of methods to "destroy" an object in unity, one of them being repositioning it or setting a flag for the spawn system to handle it.

I should make it more clear.

Comment: again most of the Unity API is not thread safe and is only allowed to be used on the Unity main thread ... and no there is only one way to [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) GameObjects in Unity ;)

Comment: @derHugo I changed the code to say "handle" instead, i think it reflects better what it should do :) Reusing objects could be a good idea.

Comment: @Ladrillo i still underlies he same issue ... you can't do anything Unity API related that would directly affect the scene in a different thread .. this includes e.g. deactivating and reusing it ...

Comment: @derHugo It's meant to work with the OP's spawn system, which should be working the unity API from the main thread. Like using an observer pattern, setting a flag, or whatever the OP considers to let their spawn system know they should handle the object somehow.